# Use Remote validation in ASP.NET MVC without form on View

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I use `Remote` attribute on my `ViewModel` in **ASP.NET MVC 4** application. Here is my simple model:

```
public class User
{
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "test test")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Email")]
    [Remote("RemoteValidateEmailLengthValidation", "Home")]

    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

And remote validation method:

```
public JsonResult RemoteValidateEmailLengthValidation(string Email)
{
    if (Email.Length > 20)
    {
        return Json("Too long email", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

I added all scripts that i need for validation on `Layout`:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
```

Write all that i need for validation in `WebConfig`:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

And add simple `Controller` that creates empty model and return `View`.

```
@model ViewModels.User

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("PostUser", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

It works only if i wrap my model in `form` and **doesn't work** if i write my `View` like this:

```
@model ViewModels.User

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@Html.EditorForModel()
```

So i have questions:

1. Why remote validation doesn't work without form? Because in Chrome debugger i see that form don't submit i see only Validation method call.
2. Which javascript method used by Remote validation? `OnChange`? Can i see it anywhere and can i change it?

Comment: Try taking out the `@` when it is within the `using` clause

Comment: The `data-val-*` attributes necessary for jquery unobtrusve validation are not rendered unless the html helper is generated inside a form so the method will never be called (this is by design). Why would you want to change the method?

Comment: @jbutler483 you don't get it. **It works** with using Form. But nothing is fired when there is no form on View. I think it should be script problem, but i don't know why.

Comment: @StephenMuecke but they are rendered without form. I just test it. But nothing is firing... It's just academic right now, but wht if i want to call something only `OnFocus`.

Comment: Not sure what your trying to do. If you want to see the actual methods in `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` open it and search "remote" (its about 3/4 down both files) But there is nothing you can change to make this work outside a form. All the method does it make a $.getJSON()` call, so you can always do that manually and render the message

Comment: The jQuery Validate plugin will **NOT** work if the input elements are not inside a `<form></form>`.  Under normal conditions, the `remote` method is fire on the `keyup` and `focusout` events, as well as when the `submit` is fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client side unobtrusive validation involves

1. On the server side: All HtmlHelper used for generating form controls
   internally call the [GetUnobtrusiveValidationAttributes](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/HtmlHelper.cs) method
   of `HtmlHelper`. Various checks are performed and if not all
   conditions are met (such as UnobtrusiveValidation has been disabled)
   then the `data-val` attributes necesary for client side validation
   are not rendered
2. On the client side: When `jquery.validation.unobtrusive.js` is
   loaded, it first checks for the existence of a `<form>` tag, then
   based on the `data-val` attributes, add the rules,messages etc. for
   use by `jquery.validate`.

The first function called is

```
parse: function (selector) {
    var $forms = $(selector)
        .parents("form")
        .andSelf()
        .add($(selector).find("form"))
        .filter("form");
    ....
```

where `selector` is the html document element. If there is no `<form>` element, `var $forms` is undefined and nothing more is executed. Client side validation simply does not work if there is no `<form>` element.

Its unclear why you would generate html form controls that are not in a form, but you could simply make your own call to the controller function, return a message and display it

```
public JsonResult RemoteValidateEmailLengthValidation(string Email)
{
    if (Email.Length > 20)
    {
        return Json("Too long email", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        return Json(null, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

and the script

```
var url = '@Url.Action("RemoteValidateEmailLengthValidation", "Home")';
var placeHolder = $('[data-valmsg-for="Email"]');
$('#Email').change(function() {
  $.getJSON(url, { Email: $(this.val() }, function(response) {
    if(response) {
      placeHolder.text(response).removeClass('field-validation-valid').addClass('field-validation-error');
    }
  });
});
```

and also handle the `.keyup` event to remove error message and reset the class name

Answer (score 0):

Cant find JsonRequestBehavior in aspnet 5

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult IsAllowedName(string FirstMidName)
{
    if (FirstMidName.ToLower() == "oleg")
    {

        //It seems that Microsoft.Asp.Net.Mvc does 
        //not contain JsonRequestBehavior enum
        return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    }
    return Json(true);
}
```

Terminal output

```
dnu build
/.../Controllers/ValidationController.cs(20,24):
DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS0103: 
The name 'JsonRequestBehavior' does not exist in the current context
Build failed.
```